# Inconsistency of electrical loss function

Tags: power, formula-derivation, loss

We have a function to calculate electrical losses for resistances and it is that $$P = I^2 \cdot R $$

If we consider this formula, our teachers generally say that if you want to decrease the losses, decrease the current, and for that increase the voltage. In brief, the more voltage, the less losses. But we also know that

$$ V = I \cdot R$$

and we can write the loss equation by combining both

$$ P = \frac{V^2}{R}$$

then as you see, if we increase the voltage, losses will be increased as well. What is wrong? Which one is right? The more voltage, the less losses, or the more voltage, the more losses ? I also ask this question for transformer like transmisson lines. We use transformer to increase the second side voltage due to reduce the losses.

Can you give me some information about this situation ? It would be better to have a proof of the loss function.

## UPDATE 1

---

By combaning the all answers, I found something else but they are also not sensible ;

The circuit which i wanted to mention is like below:

[image]

That is a transformer circuit and we can simplfy it by shifting to primary wind. And if we do it, we know resistance values will be changed by $$a = \frac{V1}{V2}$$ coefficient. With these results, we can redraw the circuit as below

[image]

And now, we can calculate loss power of the secondary wind.
$$P_{loss} = I_1^2 \cdot \ R_{loss}\cdot a^2$$ for this equation, I_1 is constant and if we reduce a constant, the loss will decrase and to do it we can increase V2. That is suitable.

But if we rewrite another formula:
$$ P_{loss} = \frac{V_1^2}{R_{loss} \cdot a^2}$$
to reduce the loss, a should increase but if we increase a, loss will increase because of first loss equation of update 1.

I can't imagine where I am missing...

Comment: You can't simply increase the voltage. In order to increase the voltage and deliver the same power to the load, you need to change the load. And when doing this, the current will decrease.

Comment: @EugeneSh. can't we use transformers to do it ?

Comment: sure we can. This is what is done for power lines. But it works for AC only.

Comment: @EugeneSh. maybe I did not indicate that I asked the question for power lines.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a problem with power equations](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/271631/i-have-a-problem-with-power-equations)

Comment: @MituRaj actually not same because in your question power is not constant and not used transformers. You dont reduce the losses, you want to increase power of the load. But thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What they appear to be talking about is wire losses. The wire appears as a resistance in series with the load. The more current, the more voltage is lost in the wire (I ⋅ R).
To reduce the losses for a given power you reduce the current, and increase the voltage so that the power at the load is the same. To do this you need to transform the voltage up at the source and down at the load, so the voltage is only higher on the transmission wires.

Example:
You are trying to provide 10,000 Watts of power over 50,000 Ft of #0 cable.
That wire will be around 5 ohms per conductor, so 10 ohms for the circuit.

At 1000 V you would need 10 A to get 10,000 W. So your loss will be 10 A times 10 ohms = 100 V, at the load you would have 900 V at 10A for 9000 W, a 10% loss.

Convert the voltage up to 10,000 V and you only need 1 A to get 10,000 W, so you losses would be 1 A times 10 ohms = 10 V. At the load you would have 9990 V at 1 A for 9990 W, a 0.1% loss.

This is why commercial electricity is distributed at high voltages and then stepped down at the load end.

Adding a couple of diagrams. They're not perfect but hopefully they will make it clearer.
[image: power distribution lower voltage]

[image: power distribution higher voltage]

Comment: when we consider your calculations, it is right excatyl but what about mathematical equation ? Mathematical equation  says it is not right for me.

Comment: @Wtow  I suggest that you draw out the circuits, do one with a 1000 V source, a 100 ohm load, and 10 ohms of resistance between the them to represent the wires. Then draw another with a 10,000 V source, 10,000 ohm load, and the same 10 ohms for the wires. Calculate the current, power lost in the 10 ohm wires, and power delivered to the load in each. Keep in mind that to keep the power at the load the same in our calculations we need to increase the load impedance, in the real world we would use transformers to step the voltage up and down and this is what would change the impedance.

Comment: I tried to do what you said and formulize and updated the question but the result is same. It is like \$ y = x(y)\$ and \$ x = y(x)\$, we have two variable that is in depend each other. If you want to critisize one of them, you should include another one but if you want to criticise another one you should include first one. It is like infinity loop

Comment: It's really not that hard, Lets say your house breaker panel is 110V @ 200A, if the power company had to send 110V @ 200A through miles of cable there would be a lot of loss. So they send the power over the wires at something like 22KV. @ 1A This lower current reduces the losses in the wires. Then a transformer on the pole outside your house steps the voltage down to 110V and the current up to 200A.

Comment: yes it is simple, but why it does not fit with theory ? If we say that, we should have some theory, experiement or something else, is it not ?

Comment: @Wtow It absolutely does fit the theory. You are just applying the theory incorrectly.
I am going to add a couple of diagrams to my answer to try to make it clearer.

Comment: I think I excatly understand now. We say \$ P = I^2 \cdot R \$ and \$ P = \frac{V^2}{R} \$ and \$I\$ is current of the secondary winding but \$V\$ is voltage of the wire resistances. Because of that, we should calculate \$I\$ like \$ P_{load} =I\cdot V_2\$. But for \$P_{loss} = V^2 \cdot R \$, V is resistance Voltage, not \$V_2\$. And \$P_{loss} = \frac{P_{load}^2}{V_2^2}\cdot R\$.I am so glad to you to share your knowledges and help me. I will mark your answer, but it would be more detailed if you added these mathematical explanations.

Answer (score 1):

The current in the first equation is the current *through* the resistance(wire, trace, etc).  The voltage in the third equation is the voltage *across* it, the "drop".  If you reduce the resistance, the drop decreases for the same amount of current flowing through.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6QJcC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's take a look at these two situations.  You're trying to power two loads - R2 and R5 - at the end of a 10m length of 22AWG cable, which is simulated by the 530 milliohm resistors.  We will assume that the loads are smart enough to compensate for changing input voltage to keep the power they draw constant e.g. a constant efficiency DC-DC converter which is a bit of a simplification but works for this example.  In the first case, you apply 5V to the end of the cable and you find that you need to supply ~1.48A to deliver  5W to the load.  In this condition, the load is acting as a 2.3 ohm resistor with 3.4 volts across it, which means that each section of wire - out and back - has a 0.8V difference across it.  0.8V^2 / 530 mOhm = 1.2W dissipated in each length of wire for 2.4W total.

In the second case, we keep the same cable and raise the input voltage to 48V (USB-C 3.1 PD mode).  Now the load R5 acts as a 460 ohm resistor to draw the same 5W.  Current is an order of magnitude smaller at 104mA which means that each section of wire only has a 0.055V difference across it.  0.055^2 / 530 mOhm = 5.7mW dissipated in each length of wire for 11.4mW total.

So in the first case when you were powering the line with 5V, the cable itself ate up 32% of the power you supplied; in the second, only 0.23%.  The key here is seeing that the voltage you plug into the power equation is the voltage "across" the resistance in question.

Comment: Actually I wonder about voltage, not resistance. If we increase the voltage, current decrase and loss power decrase. But for third formula it is reversed, the more voltage, the more power loss. Why is this conflict ? Also no matter it is drop voltage or input voltage for me because if I calculate voltage on the wire loss resistance, I found it increases by input voltage as well.

Comment: I've added some examples above with more explanation.

Comment: This answer is sensible, they act as transformer but why can't we reflect this result to equations ?

Answer (score 0):

Let me start by saying that when considering electrical losses you can choose to think about a series resistor feeding a true load or, you can think of a resistor in parallel with the true load. In either case, the resistor represents the losses.

> *What is wrong?*

- Your first equation is for power loss due to current flow in a resistor that is in series with a load
- Your second equation is for power loss due to voltage across a resistor in parallel with the load

The two resistors are different objects; one is in series with the load and, is usually quite small in value whilst the other (in parallel with the load) is quite high in value. They are not the same resistor at all.

Comment: why do you classify the formulas like series and parallel, if I am not wrong, I know we can shift arround both formulas.

Comment: Because that's the only sense I can make of your question @Wtow. If you wish to be less ambiguous then please draw each equivalent circuit.

Comment: I edited the question with more details.

Answer (score -1):

Your formula no.2 (Ohm's law) suggests that in order to decrease current, you need to decrease voltage. Not increase. Voltage is like pressure. The more voltage, the more current.

Since `V = I * R`, you can see that resistance is just a factor between voltage and current. For fixed resistance, it's just a scaling factor. Like `y = k*x` in maths.

Example: 2 Ohm resistance means that every 1 Amp of current needs 2V voltage difference across resistor. For 2 Amps, you need 4V. For 10 Amps, you need 20V. Logic works in reverse too (From volts to amps - 3V across 2 Ohm resistor will give 3/2 Amp).

So your entire logic fails early on because of false assumption about the relationship between voltage and current.

Comment: Be careful here: "Voltage is like pressure. The more voltage, the more current." This is only guaranteed to be true for an ideal resistor. I know that is what you meant, but the casual inexperience reader may not.

Comment: But I am saying it with transformers. Power is constant and if you increase the voltage at second side, your current will be decreased at second side.

Comment: There are no "transformers" in the original question, nor are there any in your answer.z

Comment: @ElliotAlderson sorry for that, I will edit it.